# Create a filterable, sortable admin view that produces front end block

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

The goal is to produce a single block to go on the homepage with 5 linked terms from a single taxonomy vocabulary. These terms would be selected and then ordered in an admin interface by a content administrator. The taxonomy vocabulary itself my have 30-50 terms.

I thought I could create an admin view with an exposed form to select the terms and then apply draggable views to the results, but I am having trouble combining the exposed form and draggable views. I am also having trouble turning the results into a block.

Happy to ad more info if this is vague, but all of the views I have set up have been so wrong I did not want to waste anyones time by posting them here.

Would views / exposed filters / draggable views be the right way to go about this or is there a better way? I'd rather not install something huge like panels to make this happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to install 
https://www.drupal.org/project/term_queue

This contrib module gives you all you need.

Here is a screenshot, admin interface to the right, front-end block to the left.

The module provides a block automatically, for each term queue, you simply need to place it.

Good luck!

[image]

Comment: The UI is a little clunky, but this will do it!

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a new content type, which has a field with the terms that you select.

Then use views with dragableviews to display the content of the node in a view block.

---

OR... I have not tested this, but you could try using the [Bean](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module, which basically allows you to add fields to your blocks.

So create a block and add a term reference field to it. Looking at the [bean module source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/bean/tree/) it looks to have Views integration. So then you would just display your bean block content in a view block with dragableviews.

This way, you avoid having to create a node that has some url path.

Comment: I was thinking that. I was just curious if there was a better way, because there would only ever be one.

Comment: @Colin updated my answer with a possible alternative.